# view not refreshing on logout of session

Tags: angularjs

I have a navbar ul in a view that shouldn't be shown if the user isn't logged in. For this I'm using ng-show="session.exists()". When the logout button (also in the nav bar view) is clicked it calls:

```
$scope.logout = function () {
  var success = function () {
    $state.transitionTo('login');
  };
  console.log($scope.session.exists());
  Auth.logout().then(success);
  console.log($scope.session.exists());
};
```

from my log statements i can see that the see that the session is being destroyed ok but the el elements I want hidden are still visible. The elements are hidden if I refresh the page. Am I missing a trick here? I'm new to angular and have inherited a project so any suggestions greatly appreciated!

C

Answer (score 0):

Probably your function are not being fired on `ngShow` when you destroy the user session.

I suggest you to use a variable to control that, and set it on on your logout function.

In your controller:

```
$scope.loggedIn = true;
$scope.logout = function() {
    $scope.loggedIn = false;
}
```

And in your view:

```
<div data-ng-show="loggedIn">Show Me!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to update the scope variable responsible for your showing your navbar url from an asynchronous function call probably in side the success of a http call.
So try adding $scope.$digest(); just after updating the scope variable